# Incorrect caffe prediction using python

Tags: python, caffe

I'm training an Alexnet using python. I've got almost 100 percent accuracy using caffe's testing tool. But my python code returns in correct classes.
When training, I converted my data to lmdb using following code (My images are gray scale)

```
convert_imageset -resize_height=256 -resize_width=256 -shuffle -gray -backend=lmdb train.txt train_lmdb
```

And compute the mean value using:

```
compute_image_mean train_lmdb train_mean.binaryproto
```

My data layer in train.prototxt looks like:

```
layer {     
      name: "data"   
      type: "Data"    
      top: "data"    
      top: "label"
include {
     phase: TRAIN   }

 transform_param {
  mirror: false
  crop_size: 227
  mean_file: "train_mean.binaryproto"  
  }    

  data_param {
  source: "train_lmdb"
  backend: LMDB
  batch_size:64  } }
```

When testing, I use following python code:

```
data = open('train_mean.binaryproto','rb').read()
blob.ParseFromString(data) arr =
np.array(caffe.io.blobproto_to_array(blob))[0,:,:,:].mean(0)

transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data':net.blobs['data'].data.shape}) 
transformer.set_mean('data', arr.mean(1).mean(0))
transformer.set_transpose('data', (2,0,1))
transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255.0)
net.blobs['data'].reshape(1,1,227,227)

img = caffe.io.load_image('image_name', False) 
img = caffe.io.resize_image( img, (256,256), interp_order=3 )
transformed = transformer.preprocess('data', img) 
net.blobs['data'].data[...] = transformed
output = net.forward()
prediction_result = output['prob'].argmax()
```

I checked the transformed image and it looks fine. I tried not to resize but it stays the same. Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong? I've been stuck with this problem for days :-(.

[update]
I checked my deploy.prototxt and train.prototxt and they have same network structure.

Comment: Please use the code formatting for your snippets. I'd change it myself, but the edit queue is full.

Comment: Oops, sorry for that. I fixed the format.

Comment: why do you `transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255.0)`? and why do you take the `mean()` of `'train_mean.binaryproto'`?

Comment: I use set_raw_scale because I am using 0~255 scale when training(as in train.prototxt, I didn't use any scaling when training). And computing the train_mean.binaryproto is simply to align caffe input format. The mean is a scalar (about 200).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accuracy reported by caffe and pycaffe are different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474366/accuracy-reported-by-caffe-and-pycaffe-are-different)

Comment: The method in the post didn't fix my problem.

Comment: It's hard to say from just looking at the code and I'm no caffe expert, but I'd say @Shai gives the most probable reason, although the particular errors may differ. Did you check that you are actually training and evaluating in exactly the same manner (including preprocessing etc.)?

Comment: I finally fixed the problem by duplicating 3 channels instead of using 1 channel. Still don't know why it didn't work. Is there any specific thing I need to notice when training caffe using 1 channel image?