# Converting Caffe model to CoreML

Tags: ios, iphone, neural-network, caffe, coreml

I am working to understand CoreML.  For a starter model, I've downloaded [Yahoo's Open NSFW](https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw) caffemodel.  You give it an image, it gives you a probability score (between 0 and 1) that the image contains unsuitable content.

Using **coremltools**, I've converted the model to a .mlmodel and brought it into my app.  It appears in Xcode like so:

[image]

In my app, I can successfully pass an image, and the output appears as a **MLMultiArray**.  Where I am having trouble is understanding how to use this MLMultiArray to obtain my probability score.  My code is like so:

```
func testModel(image: CVPixelBuffer) throws {

    let model = myModel()
    let prediction = try model.prediction(data: image)
    let output = prediction.prob // MLMultiArray
    print(output[0]) // 0.9992402791976929
    print(output[1]) // 0.0007597212097607553
}
```

For reference, the CVPixelBuffer is being resized to the required 224x224 that the model asks (I'll get into playing with Vision once I can figure this out).

The two indexes I've printed to the console do change if I provide a different image, but their scores are wildly different than the result I get if I run the model in Python.  The same image passed into the model when tested in Python gives me an output of 0.16, whereas my CoreML output, per the example above, is far different (and a dictionary, unlike Python's double output) than what I'm expecting to see.

Is more work necessary to get a result like I am expecting?

Comment: I don't think you need to resize the buffer manually. I think CoreML handles that for you

Comment: I believe that may only be the case when using Vision.  If only using CoreML itself, I do believe the buffer does need to be resized (I can confirm; it throws an error if I pass the CVPixelBuffer without resizing).

Comment: Right. Unless you like writing, rewriting, and maintaining image handling code, it's much simpler to use Vision to feed images to your model.

Comment: @rickster I'd much rather use Vision, but with this particular model, it doesn't provide any output in the results.  When I try with CoreML, I get some results, though not what I'm hoping for.  With Vision, passing the raw image yields an empty output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are not transforming the input image in the same way the model expects.
Most caffe models expects "mean subtracted" images as input, so does this model. If you inspect the python code provided with [Yahoo's Open NSFW](https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw) ([`classify_nsfw.py`](https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw/blob/master/classify_nsfw.py#L111-L116)):

```
# Note that the parameters are hard-coded for best results
caffe_transformer = caffe.io.Transformer({'data': nsfw_net.blobs['data'].data.shape})
caffe_transformer.set_transpose('data', (2, 0, 1))  # move image channels to outermost
caffe_transformer.set_mean('data', np.array([104, 117, 123]))  # subtract the dataset-mean value in each channel
caffe_transformer.set_raw_scale('data', 255)  # rescale from [0, 1] to [0, 255]
caffe_transformer.set_channel_swap('data', (2, 1, 0))  # swap channels from RGB to BGR
```

Also there is a specific way an image is [resized to 256x256 and then cropped to 224x224](https://github.com/yahoo/open_nsfw/blob/master/classify_nsfw.py#L62-L70).

To obtain exactly the same results, you'll need to transform your input image in exactly the same way on both platforms.

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40474366/1714410) for additional information.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!  I had reviewed the classify_nsfw.py file, but had hoped that the Vision framework would take care of all of this for me.  When that failed, I opted to use CoreML, but didn't think about the need to adjust the image.  Time to figure out how to do all these conversions!

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ - In addition to what Shai pointed out, you might want to try setting `is_bgr = True` for `caffe.convert()` when generating your mlmodel, because most Caffe models use BGR inputs. By default, Core ML will convert assuming RGB input, and I imagine swapping the color channels would have a large impact on the accuracy of something looking for human skin tones.

Comment: @BradLarson Thanks for that!  I had tried converting the model with coremltools using the is_bgr flag both ways, with no difference.  Shai's response will likely need to be tackled first, and then I'll try the model again with the is_bgr tag set.  Thank you for the comment!

Comment: Would you have any guidance on how to perform the image processing in the same way Python does, but in Swift?

Comment: @ZbadhabitZ I think you better ask this as a new question.

Comment: You don't need to do the image processing in Swift. When you convert your Caffe model to mlmodel, you need to pass the correct parameters to the caffe.convert() function so that the mlmodel knows how to do the image processing for you.

Comment: I tried same model in my code. But I still didn't get desired output. Like resized image directly to 224 x 224. but it gives different output. I didn't get understanding of resize to 256 x 256 then crop to 224 x 224.

Comment: Thanks @MatthijsHollemans.  I did try that, but other than setting *is_bgr=True*, I have no idea what I'd set the bias or scale to.

Comment: As you can see in @Shai's answer, the mean colors for BGR are 104, 117, 123. I think you can leave scale alone.